# OSINT instagram tool - Terra - Usage

Tags: python-3.x, security, instagram

I properly installed the tool as shown in Github: [xadhrit/terra](https://github.com/xadhrit/terra/tree/main)

When I run the program:

```
python3 terra.py username
```

It shows
[image]

I have modified the `insta.yml` file as my own Instagram account:
[image]

But I always get the above result.... Could someone help to find out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the readme, you should use quotation marks around the username and password and make sure you have cleared out cookies from creds/settings.json before each login.